# PHP Search for a keyword (Action ') from a text file, prints all lines with that keyword, then counts how many lines are printed

Tags: php

So I just started learning PHP, and I wanted to search for a certain keyword (Action ') from a text file, then print all the lines with the keyword, then count all the lines printed.

Here's what I have so far:

```
<?php
$searchfor = 'ERR:';
echo "Lines found with the keyword " . "\"" . $searchfor . "\"" . "\n";
$array  =   array_filter(array_map(function($v){
    return (stripos($v,'Action') !== false)? $v : false;  
  },array_filter(file('sampleTest.log',FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES),function($v)
{
    return (!empty(trim($v)));
})));
# This will implode the lines
echo (!empty($array))? implode('',$array) : '';
# This will count the array
echo "<br><br>Total lines printed: " . ((!empty($array))? count($array) : 0);
?>
```

So basically it looks for a certain keyword, in this case, "ERR:" from a certain text file, then prints all of the lines with "ERR:" and then it counts all the lines printed.

So what I wanted to do was look for the keyword (**Action '**). That's a space after the word Action and a single apostrophe. But it seems like it doesn't read the apostrophe('). 
It prompts me this error in CMD:

' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in C:\xampp\php\newTest.php on line 11

' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in C:\xampp\php\newTest.php on line 11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simplified version of your code.

```
<?php
$searchfor = "Action '";
$file = file_get_contents("sampleTest.log");
$matches = array();
echo "Lines found with the keyword " . "\"" . $searchfor . "\"" . "\n";

$lines = explode(PHP_EOL,$file);

foreach($lines as $line){
    if (strpos($line, $searchfor) !== false){
        $matches[] = $line;
        echo $line."<br>";
    }
}


if(!empty($matches))
    echo "<br><br>Total lines printed: ".count($matches);
else
    echo "<br><br> No matches.";


?>
```

The script will read the log file and save each line separately. It then goes through all lines and if the search word is in the line, it prints the line and saves it to the matches array that is counted at the end of the script.

Comment: Hi! There's an error in your code, I'm currently trying to run it in CMD.

This is the only output of the code:
Lines found with the keyword "Action \'"
<br><br> No matches.